# display image in react as png/jpg went wrong

Tags: reactjs, blob

I'm fetching a member's personal data from a react table and I want to display the field's `data_image` that stores blob as a png/jpg image,
but I get this symbol instead
[image]

This is the code I've tried.

```js
      <td>{member.image_data && <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${member.image_data.toString('base64')}`} />}</td>
```

can you solve the problem?